# Extracción o división de texto entre " " en R

Tags: r

Tengo que extraer texto dentro de una lista de caracteres en R, donde algunos registros se componen de 1 sólo nombre y otros de 2 nombres separados entre `""`.

No consigo:

- o extraer el 2 nombre de entre las comillas
- o dividir la lista en dos, una con el primer nombre y otra con el segundo nombre, para aquellos elementos de la lista que lo tengan, o un blanco donde no haya ese segundo nombre.

¿Alguien ha solucionado algo similar? No consigo que me lea las comillas.

---

La lista contiene registros con 1 o 2 nombres

```
[1] "Pedro Ramirez" "José Lamela"
[2] "Edurne Martin"
[3] "Mario Carmona"
```

Salida esperada:

1. List con nombres en primera posición
2. List con los que están en segunda posición y un blanco o un NA para los elementos de la lista origen que solo tienen 1 nombre.

He probado `unlist`, pero los elementos con 1 solo nombre los repite en la 2da. columna.

```
lista1
[1] "Pedro Ramirez" 
[2] "Edurne Martin" 
[3] "Mario Carmona"
lista2 
[1] "José Lamela" 
[2] "Edurne Martin" 
[3] "Mario Carmona"
output deseado en lista 2:
[1] "José Lamela" 
[2]  
[3]
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de tus datos de entrada y del código que usas para leerlos?

Comment: La lista contiene registros con 1-2 nombres
[1] "Pedro Ramirez" "José Lamela" [2] "Edurne Martin" [3] "Mario Carmona" 
Output: 
1. List con nombres en primera posici'on
2. List con los que est'an en segunda posici'on y un blanco o un NA para los elementos de la lista origen que solo tienen 1 nombre. 
He probado unlist, pero los elementos con 1 solo nombre los repite en la 2da. columna. 
lista1
[1] "Pedro Ramirez" 
[2] "Edurne Martin" 
[3] "Mario Carmona"
lista2 
[1] "José Lamela" 
[2] "Edurne Martin" 
[3] "Mario Carmona"
output deseado en lista 2:
[1] "José Lamela" 
[2]  
[3]

Comment: Edité tu pregunta con lo que comentaste. No obstante, no está claro cómo tenés estos datos ni si hay o no comillas presentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entendí mal tu ejemplo, tienes una estructura como la siguiente:

```
lista <- list(c("Pedro Ramirez","José Lamela"), 
              "Edurne Martin",  
              "Mario Carmona")
lista
[[1]]
[1] "Pedro Ramirez" "José Lamela"  

[[2]]
[1] "Edurne Martin"

[[3]]
[1] "Mario Carmona"
```

Es decir una "lista" de vectores, algunos de estos vectores tienen más de un elemento como es el primer caso. De esto quieres lograr generar dos listas, la primera con los primeros nombres de cada elemento y la segunda con los siguientes nombres de cada elemento, en caso que un elemento no lo tuviera habría que indicar `NA`.

Lo primero que se me ocurre es normalizar la lista para que cada vector tenga la misma cantidad de elementos

```
m <- max(unlist(lapply(lista, length)))
lista_normalizada <- lapply(lista, function(x)  c(x, rep(NA,m - length(x))))
lista_normalizada

[[1]]
[1] "Pedro Ramirez" "José Lamela"  

[[2]]
[1] "Edurne Martin" NA             

[[3]]
[1] "Mario Carmona" NA
```

- En primer lugar obtenemos la máxima cantidad de elementos de cada uno de los vectores de la lista: `m <- max(unlist(lapply(lista, length)))`, en este caso nos diría `2`
- Luego agregamos a cada elemento de la lista tantos `NA` para hacer que cada vector tenga el mismo tamaño: `lapply(lista, function(x)  c(x, rep(NA,m - length(x))))`

Teniendo normalizada la lista podemos ahora convertirla en una matriz simplemente para trabajar de forma más sencilla y clara:

```
mat <- matrix(unlist(lista_normalizada), ncol = m,  byrow = TRUE)
mat
     [,1]            [,2]         
[1,] "Pedro Ramirez" "José Lamela"
[2,] "Edurne Martin" NA           
[3,] "Mario Carmona" NA
```

Ahora sí es sumamente simple generar las dos listas que esperas

```
list(mat[, 1])
[[1]]
[1] "Pedro Ramirez" "Edurne Martin" "Mario Carmona"

list(mat[, 2])
[[1]]
[1] "José Lamela" NA            NA
```

Comment: entendiste perfectamente el ejemplo. Eso era lo que buscaba. Gracias por ayudar a los que estamos literalmente comenzando con R.

Answer (score 1):

Alternativamente se puede hacer con pura manipulación de listas, sin pasarlo a matriz.

```
library(tidyverse)                     #Para map, transpose, %>% , as_vector

lista <- list(c("Pedro Ramirez","José Lamela"), 
          "Edurne Martin",  
          "Mario Carmona")              #Por si alguna vez se pierde la respuesta aceptada y queda esta. 

largo_max <- max(lengths(lista))        #Obtengo el valor del vector más largo de la lista.
map(lista, `length<-`, largo_max)  %>%  # length<- "rellena" con NA hasta hacer llegar al largo especificado. 
                                        #map() para que lo haga en cada elemento de lista.  
  transpose() %>%                       #Traspongo la lista
  map(as_vector)                        #Simplifico un nivel para que sea una lista de vectores y no una lista de listas.
```

Obtengo:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Pedro Ramirez" "Edurne Martin" "Mario Carmona"

[[2]]
[1] "José Lamela" NA            NA
```